# prove that $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ is Uniform continuous with $\epsilon ,\delta$ ...

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I have to prove that $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ is Uniform continuous in $[0,\infty)$ (with $\epsilon ,\delta$ formulas...)

I wrote the definition: (what I have to prove):

$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad s.t. \quad \forall x,y\in [0,\infty) : \quad |x-y|<\delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $

So I tried developing $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)| = |\log(\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2})| $...

now this is where I try to make it bigger and simplify the expression so i can choose the right $\delta$ which depends on the $\epsilon$, and then say that if the simplified bigger expression is still smaller than $\epsilon$ then of course the original $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is smaller than $\epsilon$

but what can I do with this expression? any algebraic tricks?

Comment: Do you know that every function which is differentiable and has bounded derivative is uniformly continuous?

Comment: No, unfortunately we haven't proved that yet. we have to try to prove it without it

Answer (score 6):

By the mean value theorem,
$$f(x)-f(y) = f'(c)(x-y) = \frac{2c}{1+c^2}(x-y),$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$.

Show that $$ \left|\frac{2c}{1+c^2}\right| \le 1,$$
for example using the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{2c}{1+c^2}$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: $$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks I should have known that. About the AM-GM inequality, is this the right use of it ? $$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\le\frac{2x}{x^2}\Rightarrow\frac{2x}{x^2}\le1\Rightarrow \frac{x+x}{2}\le\sqrt{x^2}\Rightarrow x=x$$

Comment: You may use it, but directly $\frac{1+c^2}{2} \geq \sqrt{c^2}$.

Comment: @mrf, don't we need to show that the function is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: The function is differentiable over the reals. That is because $x \mapsto 1+x^2$ maps into the differentiability range of $\log$. You can use the fact that $|c| \le \max \{ 1, c^2 \}$ to conclude that
$$
\left| \frac{2c}{1+c^2} \right| \le \frac{2 \max\{1,c^2\}}{1+c^2} \le 2. 
$$
You get a bigger Lipschitz constant with less work, but you still show uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* You can use that $|\log (1+ z)| \leq z$ valid for $z\geq 1$. Thus, for $x>y$
$$\left|\log \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2}\right)\right| \leq \frac{x^2-y^2}{1+y^2}
\leq  \frac{x+y}{1+y^2} (x-y)= \frac{2y +(x-y)}{1+y^2}(x-y) .$$

Moreover, for $x<y$
$$\left|\log \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2}\right) \right| =
\left|\log \left(\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}\right) \right| \leq \frac{y^2-x^2}{1+x^2}
\leq  \frac{x+y}{1+x^2} (y-x) =\frac{2x+(y-x)}{1+x^2} (y-x).$$

Comment: I dont understand this first transition:$$\left|\log \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2}\right)\right| \leq \frac{x^2-y^2}{1+y^2}$$ can you please elaborate?

Comment: You apply the inequality $\log(1+z) \leq z$ with $z=(x^2-y^2)/(1+y^2)$

Comment: Could you please explain also how you got rid of the 2y or 2x ?

Comment: @user1685224: as in mrf's answer, you have to show that $|2c/(1+c^2)| \leq 1$.

Comment: but that means using the derivative isn't it? I thought we're not allowed to use it in this question.

Comment: @user1685224: as it is indicated in mrf's answer, you can us the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality) to show that $\frac12(1+c^2) \geq \sqrt{c^2} =|c|$.

Comment: @Fabian why did you use $z=(x^2-y^2)/(1+y^2)$ ? Shouldn't it be $|\log (1+ x)| \leq x$ , $|\log (1+ y)| \leq y$ therefore: $|\log (1+ x)|-\log (1+ y)| \leq x-y$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: the question was about the function $\log(1+x^2)$ and not $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Yes I know, I don't understand why there's $x^2-y^2$ in the numerator...

Comment: @Ginkin: because $(1-x^2)/(1-y^2) = 1 + (x^2 -y^2)/(1+y^2)$.