# Is $f(x) = \ln (x^2 + 1) $uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) : [0,\infty ) → \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(x) = \ln(x^2 + 1)$$

Prove/disprove

that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: HINT: if the derivative $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Belle: See my answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271785

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$|f'(x)| = \Bigg|\frac{2x}{x^2  +1}\Bigg| \leq 1 $$

its minimum and maximum are at $x = \pm 1$.

This shows that $f$ is Lipschtz.

Comment: Basically this is what the mean value theorem is!

Comment: It's a corollary, yes. That's not what is says though.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can use the Mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint: Does this condition höld?**

$$\forall (x, y) \in [0, \infty), \exists (a, C)\in[0, \infty)$$
$$ \mbox{such that} $$
$$ \left|\ln\left(x^2+1\right)- \ln\left(y^2+1\right)\right| \leq C\left\|x-y\right\|^a $$